# Firebase Recycler Adapter without any object model

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase in my application where I have to show a list of items using Firebase Recycler Adapter. Please refer the given image below:

[image: Database Image]

For a specific list, I have to show all the group keys in the RecyclerView, but as you can see, the items under Group are no objects and only contain an array of length N, example: **av** or **a** under Group tag. For these values, how can I show them using a  Firebase recycler Adapter? Is there anyway,  I can avoid creating a model for the same? need your help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Im wondering but why didnt you want to use POJO(object model) here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` to handle the items under `Dcu1/Group/av`, then your model it going to be a `String`:

```
new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<String, MyViewHolder>(
        String.class, 
        R.layout.my_list_item,
        MyViewHolder.class, 
        ref.child("Dcu1/Group/av")
)
```